# Add and remove an icon on a JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface

hi i have a label that i have set a icon for it, i want to remove this icon after clicking on a button, what is the method for it?

Comment: Post your existing code, so we can see what you are talking about.

Comment: You need to give us more details if you need help...

Answer (score 16):

```
// Create icon
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/foo/bar/baz.png"));

// Create label
final JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Hello, World", icon, JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

// Create button
JButton btn = new JButton("Click Me");
btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    // Remove icon when button is clicked.
    lbl.setIcon(null);

    // **IMPORTANT** to call revalidate() to cause JLabel to resize and be repainted.
    lbl.revalidate();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 10):

```
label.setIcon(null)
```

in the event handler that handles the button click, if you're using Swing.

Comment: +1 for actually posting what comes to mind when reading the question.

Comment: Accept his answer if it helped you, so other people can learn too!